# Query related to Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

We have scenario, where we are planning to use Azure Traffic Manager with External Endpoint. Due to some technical reason, we can not main external endpoint in azure traffic manager, rather we plan to use Public DNS entry which will be pointing to IP used by URL for external endpoint. Example: Proxy is having Public DNS entry called abc.com which is resolving to Public IP 192.168.0.1 used by Proxy server. We plan to create another fail-over site using Traffic manager where plan add this site as def.com resolving to Public IP 192.168.0.1

I have concerned if it will work.

Comment: This is a question for ServerFault, not StackOverflow, since it's not programming-related. When you repost there, maybe clarify a bit more? The question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it shouldn't work.  Of course, you'll need to test it.

The normal DNS design with Traffic Manager is:

- Your vanity domain CNAME yoursite.trafficmanager.net
- yoursite.trafficmanager.net CNAME yourendpoints.yourapp.com

The first CNAME you have to set up.  The second one is provided by Traffic Manager (the possible values of yourendpoints.yourapp.com correspond to the Traffic Manager endpoints you configure).